# Spring Boot logging : use of system variables in log4j2.xml

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am running spring boot application as jar.

```
java -Dlogs.location=<path/to/my/logs> -jar my-app.jar
or 
java -Dlogs.location=<path/to/my/logs> -jar my-app.jar --logs.location=<path/to/my/logs>
```

---

Here is a sample log4j2.xml configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration >
    <Properties>
        <Property name="base.log.dir">${sys:logs.location}</Property>
    </Properties>
....
</Configuration>
```

Spring boot app is creating **${sys:logs.location}** folder instead of correctly resolving system properties from jvm args.

Same configuration file working fine with Spring application. 
I am unable to make logs.location configurable with my custom log4j2.xml file. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Please refer this [sample project on github](https://github.com/shishirchaturvedi/customized-logging)

I am using [log4j2-spring.xml](https://github.com/shishirchaturvedi/customized-logging/blob/master/src/main/resources/log4j2-spring.xml#L4) to configure log4j2.

I have looked at the [StackOverflow q's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859509/how-to-make-log4j2-configurable-by-environment-using-spring-boot-1-3-6-release). This answer reads properties bundle. But I want to read sys properties

Comment: Try to rename `log4j2.xml` to `log4j2-spring.xml`. According to documentation if you're using standard one spring does not have full control over it http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, Thanks for your comment. I have tried log4j2.xml and log4j2-spring.xml both. I have added my github link in q's. Please have a look.

Comment: This issue is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14877698/5055762

Comment: BTW java option -Dlogs.location=<path/to/my/logs> has to be before -jar option - everything after -jar <file>.jar will be considered an application argument and not a java option - therefore use instead java -Dlogs.location=<path/to/my/logs> -jar my-app.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a property like

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="filePathVar"> ${sys:filepath:-/logs/app.log} </Property>
</Properties>
```

and use filePathVar like "${filePathVar}" in your xml file
and refer this for runtime args - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37439625/5055762

Note - /logs/app.log will be the default value if none is passed as a runtime arg

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how I solved it. In fact, I have used both sys and env based on different use cases. Details about sys/env are : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#EnvironmentLookup. I got it working long time back and moved on. It's been ages since I looked at my own questions. Thank you for looking at it and posting your answer.

Comment: Awesome! This was very helpful. The properties file equivalent is `property.filePathVar=${sys:filepath:-/logs/app.log}`