# log4j 2 Async JDBC appender

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am using **log4j 2** to log messages into the mySQL DB using JDBC appender. I want to make that process **asynchronous** because it should support large no of users to log the data into DB at the same time. I have to prevent **lock contention**. I have log4j.properties as follows:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, DB

# Define the DB appender
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

# Set JDBC URL
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/test

# Set Database Driver
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Set database user name and password
log4j.appender.DB.user=root
log4j.appender.DB.password=root

# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO logs VALUES('%X{username}','%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','%C','%p','%m')

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

1. What are the changes required in the above log4j.properties to behave asynchronously or create the corresponding log4j.xml?
2. How can I configure the above properties to have a buffer size to do a batch insert into the database?

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html look at Async appender. You could wrap your jdbc appender in an Async appender

Comment: As for your second question, there is a buffer size parameter . Please refer the above link

Comment: @IndraneelBende  It says <ConnectionFactory class="net.example.db.ConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" /> to get the credentials. How can I put the credentials in the log4j.xml instead of putting the credentials into the java file?

Comment: why would u want to do that? Its easier in a java file.

Comment: As to answer your question, the different options are documented here-

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

I prefer using bundle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859509/how-to-make-log4j2-configurable-by-environment-using-spring-boot-1-3-6-release

This is a good example for bundle.