# Can spring-boot application.properties file woking with log4j2.xml configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I want to define high-level file logging in application.properties as a convenience to leverage my log4j2.xml file configuration. By itself my log4j2 config is working fine, however I was hoping to control logging levels and log file and path info from the application.properties file. I have the spring-boot-starter-log4j2 dependency in the application's pom file.

In log4j2.xml I have as one of the properties

```
<Property name="LOG_FILE">${LOG-DIR}/test.log</Property>
```

, where LOG-DIR is defined in another (previous) property in the same file. In my application.properties file, I have

```
logging.file=LOG_FILE
```

as a property, plus several level properties such as

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

none of these log-related properties as defined in my application.properties file are working to build the corresponding log file. Again, when I simply use log4j2.xml by itself it works fine, but wanted to take advantage of the convenience of application.properties for logging configuration.

Any insights into what I am doing wrong are greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: In case you need different property values in log4j2.xml config for different spring profiles (dev, test, prod, etc.). You could access spring profile files like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70471889/4768635

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you are looking at [Property Substitution](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution) feature of `log4j2`.

You can define logging property in `application.properties` file like below:

```
log.file.path=/myDir/logpath
```

And then the property(s) lookup defined as `Property` in `log4j2.xml`:

```
<Configuration>  
  <Properties>  
      <property name="LOG_FILE">${bundle:application:log.file.path}</property> 
  </Properties>
```

Now all the property can be referred in same `log4j2.xml` with `${propertyName}` notation, which eventually points to values from `application.properties` file.

Comment: But what if I have defined logging.file.path in a YAML configuration?

Comment: Spring Boot will automatically find and load application.properties and application.yaml files.

Comment: @ChetanOswal - Missed this one, yes as roottraveller already alluded. Spring supports both YML & Properties file configuration, so either with work. You can in fact have both yml & properties files under the same project with different attributes, and spring load it for you just fine.

Comment: I tried - `<Properties>  
      <property name="LOG_FILE">${bundle:application:logging.file.name}</property> 
  </Properties>  `. It didn't work. Got error - `Can't find bundle for base name application, locale en_US`. But I have that file in src/main/resources path. I'm using application.yml. I found that isue is only with YML file. If you use properties file, then the above works fine. I need solution for YML file.