# Migrating from log4j1 to log4j2. properties file configuration

Tags: log4j2

How to provide the loggers for different environments in a single `log4j2.properties` file.
In my application we have three environments and each environment we are logging different log level

```
#Different log level
INT =DEBUG

QA=INFO

PROD=WARN
```

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859509/how-to-make-log4j2-configurable-by-environment-using-spring-boot-1-3-6-release

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make log4j2 configurable by environment using spring boot 1.3.6.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859509/how-to-make-log4j2-configurable-by-environment-using-spring-boot-1-3-6-release)